# Trouble understanding Sakurai's calculation of $\exp\left(\frac{iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right) \;S_x \; \exp\left(\frac{-iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

I'm having some trouble with a derivation in Sakurai's *Modern Quantum Mechanics* (specifically Derivation 1 on §3.2, p. 159), where he computes
$$
\exp\left(\frac{iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right) \;S_x \; \exp\left(\frac{-iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right).
$$
I don't understand how to go from 
$$
(\hbar/2)\exp\left(\frac{iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right) \; \{|+\rangle \langle-| + |-\rangle\langle+|\} \; \exp\left(\frac{-iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right)  
$$
to
$$
(\hbar/2)\left( e^{i \phi/2}|+\rangle\langle-|e^{i \phi/2} + e^{-i \phi/2}|-\rangle\langle+| \; e^{-i \phi/2}\right)  .
$$

Is it just a matter of expanding out the Taylor series of $\exp\left(\frac{iS_Z\phi}{\hbar}\right)$?

Comment: Well, what is $S_z|+\rangle$ equal to, for example?

Comment: It would be $\hbar/2 |+ \rangle$ ?

Comment: Ok. Do you also understand that if $A|a\rangle=a|a\rangle$ then $e^A|a\rangle=e^a|a\rangle$?

Comment: I see that now, thanks!

Comment: @SnopD. If you've now understood the problem, I would encourage you to write up your solution as an answer for future visitors.

Comment: @AaronStevens I see that you added the [tag:homework-and-exercises] tag, but this seems to be just asking about a part of the book's exposition, not something that would make much sense as an assigned problem, and not something where the process matters but the answer doesn't. Personally, I wouldn't put that tag on this question. What do you think of taking it off?

Comment: @DavidZ I certainly don't think that any question asking about a book's exposition deserves that tag. In this particular instance the question and method would seem like an exercise though. The key parts of it I tried to get the OP to think through in the comments. It's an exercise in working with "eigen-things", understanding what $e$ to the power of an operator is, etc. However, I'll always default to users with more experience, so if you change it I won't take it personally.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite generally true that for any two $n\times n$ matrices $A,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$
$$
\exp(A) B \exp(-A)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}{\rm ad}_A^n B
$$
where I define
$$
{\rm ad}_A B= [A,B]=AB-BA.
$$

This is proven by replacing $A\to \varepsilon A$ for $\varepsilon \in \mathbb R$ and Taylor-expanding in $\varepsilon$. The formula is also true quite generally when $A,B$ are any elements of the universal enveloping algebra of any Lie algebra.

Since you know the commutation relations of $S_X,S_Y,S_Z$ you can then directly calculate the result

Comment: Might remind the OP of the proof of said [Hadamard lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula#An_important_lemma_and_its_application_to_a_special_case_of_the_Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff_formula).

Answer (score 1):

In general, if $\vert \ell m\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $S_z$, then
$$
e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}\vert \ell m\rangle
=\left(I+i \phi \hbar m/\hbar + \frac{1}{2}(i \phi \hbar m/\hbar)^2+
\ldots\right)\vert \ell m\rangle=e^{im\phi}\vert \ell m\rangle
$$
by definition of the exponential of an operator, and likewise
$$
\langle \ell m\vert e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}=
\left(e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}\vert \ell m\rangle\right)^\dagger
=\langle \ell m\vert e^{-im\phi}
$$
so that
$$
e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}\vert \ell m\rangle\langle \ell m'\vert e^{-i\phi S_z/\hbar} = e^{im\phi} \vert \ell m\rangle\langle \ell m'\vert 
e^{im'\phi}
$$
and you can work the rest of the calculation that way.

There is a geometric interpretation to a conjugation like $U \hat A U^\dagger$, where $\hat A$ is an operator: the transformation $U$ is just a change of basis.  In your case, $e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}$ is a change of basis obtained by rotation about $\hat z$ so you would expect under this $S_x$ to go to a linear combination of 
$S_x\cos\phi\pm S_y\sin\phi$ and $S_y$ since the $\hat x$ axis rotates to a combination $\hat x\cos\phi\pm \hat y \sin\phi$.  The difficulty is with the sign, or alternatively, to understand if $e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}$ produces a clockwise or anticlockwise rotation.

This is fixed easily enough since, by expanding 
\begin{align}
e^{i\phi S_z/\hbar}S_xe^{-i\phi S_z/\hbar} 
&=S_x+i\phi [S_z,S_x]+\frac{1}{2!}(i\phi)^2 [S_z,[S_z,S_x]]+\ldots\\
&=S_x+i\phi(iS_y)-\frac{1}{2!}(\phi)^2[S_z,iS_y]+\ldots\\
& =S_x-\phi S_y-\frac{1}{2!}\phi^2 S_x+\ldots
\end{align}
which matches the expansion of $S_x\cos\phi-S_y\sin\phi$.